# Recent reference for "why not to build RF circuits on breadboard"

Tags: rf, breadboard, 433mhz

I've noticed the occasional

> I've built my FM modulator/RF mixer/433 MHz oscillator according to plans from The Internet on a breadboard, now it doesn't work.

We can usually refer the author to something existing, pointing out in comments that breadboard will not do at RF. But we fail at actually giving empirical evidence that would be the case. That's not very good engineering practice.

Is there something we can point users to, that shows measurements?

Comment: You shouldn't build _anything_ on breadboard. It's one of the most horrible, error-prone inventions ever. If you want to troubleshoot your actual circuit rather than trouble-shooting your attempt to create it, then use experiment boards and a soldering iron. Even if your soldering skills and iron are bad, it will still give far better end results than the average breadboard nightmare.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, there are [these](https://twitter.com/azonenberg/status/1401419468824219648) writings of Andrew Zonenberg, where he measures different configurations of adjacent breadboard columns.

The real kicker is this figure:

[image: Plot of isolation between adjacent lines]

At 200 MHz, already 10% of the energy put into the field around one line can be extracted with its neighbor.